# Image on submit button

Tags: html, css

i've been trying to change my input submit button background's image, i followed many tutorials but none of them helped. The button still doesn't appear. Here is the snippet of code.

```
 <input type="submit" name="submit" value="" alt="submit">

input[type="submit"] {
  background: url(../icons/submit_icon.png) no-repeat 0 0;
  display: block;
  height: 25px;
  text-indent: -9999px;
  width: 28px;
  border: 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm working on Safari but it doesn't appear on google chrome either.

Comment: Cannot replicate - https://jsfiddle.net/3ydbeoo6/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried your code and it worked, here is the fiddle :
https://jsfiddle.net/268rLw9v/1/

I think your problem is because of the size of the image (or of the input), look in my example, I changed the width and height of the input because the image I use is bigger.

```
width: 250px; height: 280px; // I used that because of the image size
```

Be sure that your image have an appropriate size.
You can also try these css properties to see what happens :

```
background-size: cover;
background-position: center;
```

Comment: Thank you it worked, do you have any idea about how I can resize the image with css code, or do I need have the image in the right size in my project

Comment: It's often better to have the image at the final dimension but you can do it using the background-size property : http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp